# grep/awk: exclude words conditionally

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I have data formatted like this:

```
a cat
a dog
brown cat
brown dog
brown cow
brown sheep
brown fish
```

I want to filter out all of the lines starting with "brown", except `brown dog`. Is there an easy way to do this with grep or awk? I tried to use the carat negation like so:

```
grep -v "brown ^\(dog\)" corpus.txt
```

... but that didn't work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Eventually I want the output to be like this:

```
a cat
a dog
brown dog
```

Comment: What if the line starts with `brownish`? What if the line is `brown dogfish`? Include cases like those to show how you want strings anchored in your sample input/output and cases that include regexp metacharacters if such can exist in your data to show if you're trying to do string or regexp matching.

Comment: This is structured data that I've scrubbed to create a simple testcase on StackOverflow. There is no `brownish` or `dogfish` in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sir:

```
grep -vP '^brown (?!dog)' file
```

```
a cat
a dog
brown dog
```

`-P` for [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) engine use.
Check [explanations](https://regex101.com/r/Tx60MQ/1)

Comment: Thanks! In general I try not to use PCRE as my regex engine, but since this was just a one-off filter I'll allow it. This command worked for me.

Comment: I think this is the straightforward way. 'grep -v' + look around (negative look ahead).

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^brown dog/ || !/^brown/' file
```

```
a cat
a dog
brown dog
```

---

Just as an academic exercise here is a `grep` command without **experimental** `PCRE` option:

```
grep -vE '^brown($|[^ ]| ([^d]|$)| d([^o]|$)| do([^g]|$))' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^brown/ && !/dog$/{next} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Ok, it's past midnight over here. I'm going to post this awk:</s>

```
$ awk '!(/brown/ && !/dog/)' file
```

... and think it thru in the morning. :D Good night.

Nope, couldn't sleep, had to solve it:

```
$ awk '!/^brown/ || /dog/' file
```

Output:

```
a cat
a dog
brown dog
```

Comment: add start of line anchor `!/^brown/`,

Comment: @karakfa Thanks. _After midnight, We gonna let it all hang down..._

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you specifically want to accept "brown dog" only, but perhaps you just want something like:

```
sed -e '/^brown/{/dog/!d;}'
```

This will delete all lines that start with "brown" unless they match the string "dog".  Or maybe you want to be stricter and do:

```
awk '!/^brown/ || $2 == "dog"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`:

```
$ awk '!(/^brown/ && $2!="dog")' file
a cat
a dog
brown dog
```